# Retrieve the mean of results from imputed data PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

First of, I'm pretty new to this site and coding in general so please explain in simple terms as I'm still learning! Thanks

Ok, so I've got a database of results. These are 1-6 ratings. I've already created the ability to retrieve certain results (user, group, all).

But now I'm wanting to alongside retrieving the group and all results to display at the top of the results a mean for each question.

So to start I'm wanting something like this I believe.

```
       SELECT sum(r1), sum(r2), sum(r3) so on, 
       FROM table
```

This is where I get confused. 
I think I'd need a variable to contain these and then another that counts the amount of entries to divide the total of r1 hence the mean.

Any ideas?..

Comment: 6 point likert scale? Or 1 is low and 6 is high? If it's a likert scale here is a insight to the 5point vs 6point debat: http://www.infosurv.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Likert_Scale_Debate.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate a mean, use the `AVG` function, e.g.

```
   SELECT AVG(r1), AVG(r2)
   FROM table
```

See the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg).

Comment: Aha.. How would I then take that and print the average? Sorry.. Quite new to these functions

Comment: You could do something like `SELECT AVG(r1) col1_avg, AVG(r2) col2_avg FROM table` and then in your php code use `col1_avg` and `col2_avg` as references to obtain a result.

Comment: Would I simply print coll_avg? Or is there more too it. Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Depends on how are printing the column data now, but yes, that's pretty much it.